# Web.config and ASP.NET configuration issue

Tags: asp.net, authentication, web-config, portal, intranet

New to Microsoft Web Developer 2010 Express, and not an accomplished programmer, but I can get by ... usually.  I did make a company website with MWD 2010 and things are going great.

I'm trying to make a company portal.  I tried using the ~/Account folder that comes with new asp.net websites, but I wanted to try one from scratch on my own.  So I followed Microsoft's instructions and created one on my own in another folder called ~/Portal. --> msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/879kf95c(v=vs.80).aspx

I don't know if I made a programming mistake, or if it's with my ASP.NET Configuration, or what I think it is, my web.config file, but something happened.  The 2 folders are crossing up.  Like, I'll be in welcome.aspx on the **~/Portal**/welcome.aspx, and it'll redirect me to the **~/Account**/login.aspx page.  I made a change in the ROOT web.config file (not my Portal or Account folder):
Was:

> forms loginUrl="~/Account/login.aspx" timeout="2880"

Changed to:

> forms loginUrl="~/Extranet/welcome.aspx" timeout="2880"

But when I click the login link on Extranet/welcome.aspx, it still redirects me to Account/login.aspx.  Specifically, the URL says:
**(root)/Account/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fExtranet%2fwelcome.aspx**

Now, it will allow me to go to the ~/Portal/welcome.aspx page, but when I click the login link, it takes me to the ~/Account/login.aspx page.  Strange.

**My question is:
(a) Is this something that's easily fixable?
(b) Should I delete both folders and start from scratch?  Not a problem, but I don't want to screw anything up.  If I do this, will I have to make redactions to the root web.config file?**
(c) Is there another solution I should be using instead of following Microsoft's instructions?

There's a web.config in my root, which appears to be the one being edited by changes I make in ASP.NET Configuration, and there's one in my ~/Account folder, where the login.aspx that comes with new websites is.

Thanks for taking the time to read this, if you made it this far, and thank you for any and all help you can offer!

Comment: I came across something similar a long time ago.  This is a known issue and there is a workaround for it.  Do not delete and start from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#0.1__Toc274034230) is the article for the solution:

Here is the given solution (add this to the `<appSettings>` section in your web.config):

```
<add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
```

Comment: Hey Travis, Jon, that's unbelievable that you had a response so particular to my issue.  Thanks a ton!  I probably created a few problems myself by altering some files before really researching them through.  I really do appreciate you taking the time to read my post and respond to it.  And thanks a ton Jon for helping make that answer clear; I need all the help I can get!

Answer (score 3):

You can also go into the properties of the login pages (examples: login.aspx register.aspx etc...) and change the DestinationPageUrl

I did the same thing you did, but could not find the 'appSettings' section in my web.config file.

Comment: Thanks Colton ... appreciate the response.  This was a long time ago, and I used Travis's method to solve it, and things have been working fine since.  I appreciate you taking the time, however!

Comment: You bet. Just thought I'd put my two cents in, in case someone was having the same issue I was. I tried Travis' method to no avail and hacked my way to a solution that worked for me. Thanks!